# Reading data from a database in Anylogic

Tags: database, agent, anylogic

I am designing a simulation model with Anylogic to simulate the assembly process of an automotive company. I have a database that records all the car models with their cycle times for every work station. I want the model to read work station's delay time from the database; this mean, the code must pull the cycle time where the car model name matches the current agent being delayed.

I tried the code: SELECT "cycle time column name" FROM "Table_name" WHERE car_model column name" = "Agent_type.this"

it didnt work out.

Any idea how to go abt this ?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF :) what does "it didnt work out." mean? Please help us help you. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some info but at least tell us the erroer :-).  Also show the database table setup (screenshots please), data types for each column... Make our lives easy

Comment: Hey Benjamin, the error msg I got says : "Agent cannot be resolved to a type". I also tried the code: " SELECT ct1 FROM car_models WHERE unit_name = agent.unitName =="VW" ? "VW"; with this, the model runs, but it doesnt pull the correct data. the dabase has two one column for the car models (String type) and remaing column for the cycle time for each work station (Integer type). i hope this clarifies. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your QL query is wrong. `Agent_type.this` refers to the specific agent instance but your SQL query expects a String at that point.

So in your `Agent_type` agent type, you should have a variable or parameter of type String that already holds the car model name. Let's say it is called `modelName`.

Now your SQL would work using

`SELECT "cycle time column name" FROM "Table_name" WHERE car_model column name" = "Agent_type.modelName"`

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thanks a lot for your input.   I tried that, the SQL seems to accept it but I now received a java error msg: "Cannot make a static reference to a non-static field Agent_type.modelName" any idea how to fix it.

Comment: here is the complete code: SELECT ct1 FROM car_models WHERE unit_name = Car.unitName =="VW" ? "VW" : Car.unitName == "GTS" ? "GTS" : Car.unitName == "HB" ? "HB" :
Car.unitName == "TGM" ? "TGM" : "CLA"

Comment: You need to not refer to the agent-type "Car" but to an individual Car agent (that has it's specific unitName). How you do that depends on where in the model you call the SQL statement and how it is setup. If you cannot figure it out, please post a new question with a screenshot and good description :-)